# Regex matching a character different from the first

Tags: ruby, regex, pattern-matching

Im trying to use regex to match a pattern like this:

(any letter) (a different letter) (the same letter again)

so for example:

these are all valid examples:

```
aba
bcb
dbd
```

these are not valid:

```
aab
aaa
bac
```

Im trying to do it in this way:

```
(.)[^\1]\1
```

However, this still matches case where the second letter is similar to the first letter (e.g: `aaa`). See here: http://rubular.com/r/TTGEcyhE9g

Is there a way in regex to match `any letter except the captured one`?

Comment: Are you sure that `[^\1]` even works?  My understanding is that you can't put a backreference into a character class, because the latter needs a hard coded list of characters.

Comment: I see, maybe that's the problem. What can I do in this case?

Comment: Use a lookahead to restrict a char: [`/(.)(?!\1).\1/`](http://rubular.com/r/0KxUEwgnsd).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nice one...that could be an answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backreferences are not valid in character ranges. As explained by Wiktor Stribiżew below, you are defining raw characters here, in your case the `\x01` (SOH, Start of heading) character.

As a workaround, you could use a negative lookahead as follows:

```
(.)(?!\1).\1
```

Here, you are matching any character which is not followed by the same character (which is not consumed) followed by any character (but a different one because of the negative lookahead), followed by the first character again.

You can learn more about lookahead and lookbehind in the [Ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors).

Comment: You may add that `[^\1]` matches any char other than `\x01` char  (*SOH, Start of heading*). And to make `.` match any char, add `m` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

If you like using regex, then Wiktor's suggestion has you covered.  But, it is easy enough to write a basic Ruby script which does the assertions:

```
input = "aea hello"
if input[0] == input[2] && input[0] != input[1]
    print "match"
else
    print "no match"
end
```

Comment: Thank you. the regex is a part of a bigger regex, for that I prefer to use wiktor's suggestion.